# Running two linux commands via PHP, don't wait for first to end before executing second

Tags: php, linux, bash, centos, centos6

This is pretty weird, and I searched and tried everything, but I think I'm just making a dumb syntax error here.

I'm trying to run a stress test on the CPU , then immediately limit it's cpu usage to 30% , all this via PHP. The test is also run under another user and with a specified name so it can be limited. The stress test starts fine, but I can see the PHP file still loading, and it ends the second the stress test ends.

Here's some of the ways I tried doing it

```
$output = exec('sudo runuser -l test -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName stress -c 1 -t 60s & cpulimit -e MyUniqueProcessName -l 30"');

$output = exec('sudo runuser -l test -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName stress -c 1 -t 60s > /dev/null & cpulimit -e MyUniqueProcessName -l 30"');
```

The whole purpose of this is because I am writing a script for a game hosting website, and I want to limit the resource consumption of each server to improve quality and not let someone hog all the resources.
Basically, instead of the stress test, a game server will run.

edit::

here's what I have now:

I need to run the stress under "test" , but the cpulimit under either sudo apache or root, because it requires special permissions. The stress still starts fine but it eats 99.9%

```
passthru('sudo runuser -l test -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName stress -c 1 -t 60s &" & sudo cpulimit -e MyUniqueProcessName -l 30 -i -z');
```

I can't see the cpulimit in the process list after doing this https://i.stack.imgur.com/730Eu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `&&` does more or less the opposite of what you want. :-) When you do `A && B` in Bash, that means, "Run command A and wait until it's done; if it succeeded, then run command B."

By contrast, `A & B` means, "Run command A and then immediately run command B."

So you're close to right in your command, but just getting tripped up by using two `bash` commands (should only need one) and the `&&`.

Also, did you try running each command separately, outside PHP, in two terminals? I just downloaded and built both [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) and [cpulimit](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) (I assume these are the ones you're using?), ran the commands separately, and spotted a problem: `cpulimit` still isn't limiting the percentage.

Looking at the docs for `stress`, I see it works by forking child processes, so the one you're trying to CPU-limit is the parent, but that's not the one using the CPU. `cpulimit --help` reveals there's option `-i`, which includes child processes in what is limited.

This gets me to the point of being able to enter this in one terminal (first line shows input at the prompt; subsequent show output):

```
$> exec -a MyUniqueProcessName stress -c 1 -t 60s & cpulimit -e MyUniqueProcessName -l 30 -i
[1] 20229
MyUniqueProcessName: info: [20229] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
Process 20229 found
```

Then, in another terminal running `top`, I see:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
20237 stackov+  20   0  7164  100    0 R 30.2  0.0   0:04.38 stress
```

Much better. (Notice that outside the Bash shell where you aliased it with `exec -a`, you will see the process name as `stress`.) Unfortunately, I also see another issue, which is `cpulimit` remaining "listening" for more processes with that name. Back to `cpulimit --help`, which reveals the `-z` option.

Just to reduce the complexity a bit, you could leave the alias off and use the PID of the `stress` process, via the special Bash variable `$!`, which refers to the PID of the last process launched. Running the following in a terminal seems to do everything you want:

```
stress -c 1 -t 60s & cpulimit -p $! -l 30 -i -z
```

So now, just change the PHP script with what we've learned:

```
exec('bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName stress -c 1 -t 60s & cpulimit -e MyUniqueProcessName -l 30 -i -z"');
```

...or, simpler version:

```
exec('bash -c "stress -c 1 -t 60s & cpulimit -p \$! -l 30 -i -z"');
```

(Notice the $ in the `$!` had to be escaped with a backslash, `\$!`, because of the way it's quoted when passed to `bash -c`.)

**Final Answer:**

Based on the last example you amended to your question, you'll want something like this:

```
passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test stress -c 1 -t 60s & sudo -u root cpulimit -p \$! -l 30 -i -z"');
```

When I run this with `php stackoverflow-question.php`, it outputs the following:

```
stress: info: [3374] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
stress: info: [3374] successful run completed in 60s
Process 3371 found
```

(The second two lines *only* appear after the PHP script finishes, so don't be mislead. Use `top` to check.)

Running `top` in another terminal during the 60 seconds the PHP script is running, I see:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3472 test      20   0  7160   92    0 R 29.5  0.0   0:07.50 stress
 3470 root       9 -11  4236  712  580 S  9.0  0.0   0:02.28 cpulimit
```

This is exactly what you've described wanting: `stress` is running under the user `test`, and `cpulimit` is running under the user `root` (both of which you can change in the command, if desired). `stress` is limited to around 30%.

I'm not familiar with `runuser` and don't see the applicability, since `sudo` is the standard way to run a process as another user. To get this to work, you may have to adjust your settings in /etc/sudoers (which will require root access, but you obviously already have that). That's entirely outside the scope of this discussion, but as an example, I added the following rules:

```
my-user ALL=(test) NOPASSWD:NOEXEC: /home/my-user/development/stackoverflow/stress 
my-user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:NOEXEC: /home/my-user/development/stackoverflow/cpulimit
```

Comment: It still does the same thing, runs the stress test then freezes, if I kill the stress or let it finish then it executes the limit (php page stays loading till I do this)

Comment: The PHP page *will* stay loading until the bash process completes, i.e, both processes are done.

Comment: It looks like the way you were using `cpulimit` was causing problems. I didn't have `stress` or `cpulimit` on my system, but downloaded and built them and worked through the issues. Please see the amended answer.

Comment: thanks very much for the input. the two commands used are indeed stress and cpulimit, and yes I tried running them from the console. It didn't seem to work fine with the names, but with PID it deff. worked fine. Wouldn't using the last pid launched cause a problem on a server with 24 cores? eg the wrong process getting limited? I'm pretty scared of doing stuff like this outside my single thread safety bubble

Comment: my current implementation and some more info is in the OP, please check it out

Comment: Both versions (name and PID) work identically for me. I assume you noted that they use a different switch for name and PID, `-e` and `-p`, respectively.

Regarding the last PID launched, it's the last one launched *by your shell* (that is, the `bash` command you're running), so it should be as safe (arguably safer) than running based on some name, which someone else could theoretically pick. (PIDs are unique, after all.)

Comment: Frankly, you've altogether asked three questions (how to run multiple commands simultaneously in PHP; what am I doing wrong with `cpulimit`; how can I control what users commands run under) in a single question by going back and modifying it to ask more, which is kind of bad form. However, I updated the answer with one final attempt to solve all of your problems in one go. Please see the section marked **Final Answer**. I'm afraid I can't spend any more time on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and writing this answer. The reason I changed the original question so much is because meanwhile, I kept changing the code and adding more functionality(that shouldn't affect the end result) to it. Regarding runuser, I just searched how to run processes under another user and it was the first result. For some reason, you snippet still doesn't work. When ran via php stress.php , it outputs FALSE, and when run by opening the script in a browser, it stresses and still hogs 99.9% . Doesn't running one under test and the other under root affect \$! ?